# QGIS 3.24 - how to use "Create Text at Point" tool

Tags: qgis, annotation, text

I selected to "Create Text at Point" tool in an attempt to annotate my map in QGIS version 3.24. However, this just caused the word "Text" to appear on my map. I tried to figure out how to delete it, but in doing so I added the word "Text" to my map several more times. I can't figure out how to delete these, or find anything at all online about the "Create Text at Point" tool.

How can I save my map from being riddled with the word "Text".

Answer (score 2):

- Click the `Modify Annotations` from the `Annotations toolbar`.
- Select the text annotation that you added and press the <kbd>Delete</kbd> button on your keyboard to delete it.

[image]

Please note that you cannot select all the annotations at once to delete them all. You need to delete each annotation one by one.